# Scaling different faces of a cube acts differently Blender

Tags: blender

I just started to work on my first project in Blender and I already have a problem. It seems as scaling works somewhat weirdly on my cube.

Here's a GIF to show you what I mean:

[image: Image from Gyazo]

The bottom face doesnt change the form of the cube but the side face does.

What should I do or change to make the bottom face act like the side face?

Here is the resault I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is an overlaid face on the bottom face of the house. You probably used extrude on this face before. Everytime you used extrude, either on vertices or edges or faces, an new one would be created. If you clicked right mouse or cancel it, the newly created would be hidden as it is overlaid with the original. Just delete the face and vertices.

Comment: I selected the bottom face and press x to dissolve edges, now it is working. Ty for your idea